# Deployment of drools(6.0) rules application in tomcat server

Tags: drools

I have developed my rules application using drools and would like to deploy it to Tomcat along with my other webapplciation that invokes rules. How do I go ahead with this?

Im using Drools 6.0.

Comment: My guess would be to start by putting the Drools JARs in the WEB-INF/lib of your web deployment.

Comment: And build the knowledge base and session inside my calling application? Where do I put my drl files? Have that also need to be packaged inside the calling webapplication(WAR)?

Comment: Every web app belongs in a WAR, of course.  Put all the rest of that stuff in the CLASSPATH, which means under WEB-INF/classes.  Your Drools code should access those by reading from streams in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: I get that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the kie-workbench from here

http://download.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/kie-drools-wb-distribution-6.0.1.Final.zip

and then put the tomcat war inside tomcat/webapps

Comment: Workbench allows to manage the repository and does allow to create the ziped version for deployment. correct? Beyond that, I doubt